# await for Command.Execute with or without async Action

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.forms, command

I came across a strange case and I got stuck on it.

I have a Popup View + ViewModel which as a button inside. The Popup gets Command from other views for the execution of the button.

Now, I want to disable the button as soon as clicked, run the command and then disable it.

This is what I have now:

**PopupViewModel**

```
public override Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
{
    PopupModel model = (PopupModel) navigationData;
    ...
    _mainActionCommandToRun = model.MainActionCommand;
    ...
    return base.InitializeAsync(navigationData);
}

private void OnMainActionCommand(object obj)
{
    MainActionCommand.CanExecute(false);
    _mainActionCommandToRun.Execute(null);
    MainActionCommand.CanExecute(true);
}
```

**Some View how uses the popup**

```
await DialogService.ShowPopupAsync<PopupViewModel>(new PopupModel
{
    ...
    MainActionCommand = new Command(
        () =>
        {
            DoSomeThing();
        })
});
```

This case workes like a charm. It gets complicated when the action assigned to the command is async.

**Some View with async action**

```
await DialogService.ShowPopupAsync<PopupViewModel>(new PopupModel
{
    ...
    MainActionCommand = new Command(
       async () =>
        {
            await DoSomeThing();
        })
});
```

In this case, the _mainActionCommandToRun.Execute(null) will fire the async action and continue to the CanExecute(true).

I can't do await to the Execute because it's a void method and wrapping it with a task will not solve anything...

Basically, I have an async method that doesn't know it's an async method.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Command.ExecuteAsync() method ... 
Beside rethinking your programlogic to avoid this situation at all, or using a AsyncCommand (I think MVVM Light has such a command)  you could use a Locking/Semaphore to synchronise the threads/tasks ...

Comment: I recommend using AsyncCommand. Here's an implementation I created on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need some concept of an [asynchronous command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx). Some MVVM libraries have this built-in these days:

```
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
  Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
}
```

where the `ICommand.Execute` implementation is always `async void ICommand.Execute(object parameter) => await ExecuteAsync(parameter)`. You can then define your own `AsyncCommand` that works just like `Command` except it implements `IAsyncCommand`.

Then have your view models expose `IAsyncCommand` instead of `ICommand`, and your popup logic can use that:

```
private async void OnMainActionCommand(object obj)
{
  MainActionCommand.CanExecute(false);
  await _mainActionCommandToRun.ExecuteAsync(null);
  MainActionCommand.CanExecute(true);
}
```